# App group created in Xcode does not appear in developer account console

Tags: xcode, certificate

I've created a share extension target for an ad-hoc-distributed target in Xcode. In order to share user defaults between the main app and the extension, I've enabled the app group capability for both targets, adding a new app group.

Now, when I view the share target in the project configuration view, I see the following errors:

> Provisioning profile "my adHoc profile" doesn't support the App Groups capability.
>
> Provisioning profile "my adHoc profile" doesn't support the  App Group.
>
> Provisioning profile "my adHoc profile" doesn't include the my app group groups entitlement.

[image: Screenshot of first errors]

This makes sense; when I view the capabilities tab for the target and expand the app groups entitlement, my new app group is highlighted in red, and the following errors display underneath it:

> Add the App Groups feature to your App ID
>
> Provisioning profile "my adHoc profile" doesn't support the App Groups capability
>
> Add App Groups to your App ID
>
> Provisioning profile "my adHoc profile" doesn't support the App Groups capability

[image: Screenshot of error 2]

But when I navigate to developer.apple.com -> Account -> Certificates, IDs & Profiles -> Identifiers -> My share extension App ID -> App Groups -> Configure, I don't see the App Group that I created.

[image: Screenshot of available app groups; mine is missing]

How can I add my group to the developer console so that I can select it as a group for my App ID, so that it becomes available on my provisioning profile?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it!

App Groups exist at the same (top) hierarchy as other identifiers. So to add a new one, I navigated to `developer.apple.com` -> `Account` -> `Certificates, IDs & Profiles` -> `Identifiers`, and then clicked the plus button, and then selected "App Groups" as the type of identifier.

Here's the plus button to add a new identifier:

[image: Screenshot of identifiers screen with plus button]

And here's where I chose to add an app group:

[image: Screenshot of identifier type menu with app group type selected]

After that, I just entered a name and description for the app group as per my needs.